# Array find, cannot read property length of undefined

Tags: javascript

How can I check for options without a length? Some `options` have ested `options` others dont.

The code below errors when I check for `options.length == 0`

```
const { group, data, year } = args;
return (
    data
        .find(element => {
            return element.id == year;
        })
        .options.find(element => {
            return element.id == group;
        }).options.length == 0
```

Data:

```
years: [
        {
            label: "Year 3",
            id: 1,
            options: [
                {
                    label: "Firm 01",
                    id: "xxx@xx.co.uk"
                },
                {
                    label: "Firm 02",
                    id:
                        "xxx.co.xxx@group.calendar.google.com"
                }, ....
```

Comment: Can you show the kind of data on which you're working?

Comment: Array's `find` returns element's **_value_**, not _array_

Comment: What are expected results if no nested options?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is check whether or not your variable is defined you can achieve this by:

```
if(typeof(data.options) !== 'undefined')
  //do something e.g: check if data.options.length != 0
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: But `data` is an array which will never have an `options` property

Comment: Indeed, however, if he doesn't know how many nested 'options' he will have, he can use recursion to iterate throughout the array and still, the solution above may be applied.